# Calcular ruta entre dos puntos con Google Maps en IOS

Tags: swift, swift2, google-maps, swift3

Estoy usando el `SDK` de `Google Maps` en [swift](/questions/tagged/swift) y necesito saber cómo puedo calcular la ruta que hay entre dos puntos.

Tengo las coordenadas de estos dos puntos y a través de la función `Geocoding` del `SDK` tengo también sus direcciones.

He probado con la función `Directions` añadiendo la dirección de inicio y la de fin, pero me da error.

¿Alguna posible solución?

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el código que tienes?¿Cómo es el error que recibes?¿Cuál es el mensaje?

Answer (score 2):

Esta respuesta no da solución usando servicios de Google. Existen varias alternativas a los servicios (limitados) de Google Maps. Por un lado tenemos OpenStreetMaps (OSM) y su proyecto OSRM, que trae implementados varios servicios entre ellos el servicio [`Route Service`](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.5.2/api/#route-service) que es el que interesa en este caso:

> **Route service**
>
> Finds the fastest route between coordinates in the supplied order.

En la documentación encontrarás ciertos parámetros de interés que puedes enviar en tu petición.
Así pues la solución es tan sencilla como enviar una petición HTTP con la información requerida al servicio de OSM y utilizar las geometrías devueltas por dicha petición.

Otra alternativa es disponer de tu propia cartografía y tu propio servidor, podrías implementar tu propio servicio de rutas, teniendo como repositorio de datos una base de datos PostgreSQL/PostGIS y teniendo la extensión `pgrouting`. Si tuvieses cartografía abundante y precisa, datos en tiempo real, etc, esta sería la solución que tomaría. También tendría en cuenta la extensión geográfica para esta solución, ya que la dificultad radica en conseguir datos actualizados de carreteras para toda la zona de interés.

Obviamente para hacer lo que deseas no vas a ponerte a implementar tu propia API. Investiga un poco sobre los servicios de OSM que a parte de ser gratuitos no tienen limitaciones de uso.

Answer (score 2):

He encontrado un manual bastante completo para el [sdk](/questions/tagged/sdk) de **Google Maps** para [swift](/questions/tagged/swift) en el que explica detalladamente los pasos a seguir para presentar al usuario la posición actual, crear una ruta, dibujar una ruta, añadir localizaciones intermedias, etc.

Para tu caso creo que la sección **Drawing a Route** se ajusta bastante bien a lo que pides, ya que te muestra los pasos a seguir para obtener la ruta entre una dirección de inicio y una de fin y luego dibujar la ruta correspondiente.

El tutorial es el siguiente [**A Swift Tutorial for Google Maps SDK**](https://www.appcoda.com/google-maps-api-tutorial/)

A continuación te pongo el código que creo que puede servirte de ayuda donde la URL para realizar la petición al WS de **Google** es:

```
let baseURLDirections = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?"
```

La función que se encarga de esto es la siguiente:

```
func getDirections(origin: String!, destination: String!, waypoints: Array<String>!, travelMode: AnyObject!, completionHandler: ((status: String, success: Bool) -> Void)) {
    if let originLocation = origin {
        if let destinationLocation = destination {
            var directionsURLString = baseURLDirections + "origin=" + originLocation + "&destination=" + destinationLocation

            directionsURLString = directionsURLString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

            let directionsURL = NSURL(string: directionsURLString)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                let directionsData = NSData(contentsOfURL: directionsURL!)

                var error: NSError?
                let dictionary: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(directionsData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

                if (error != nil) {
                    println(error)
                    completionHandler(status: "", success: false)
                }
                else {
                    let status = dictionary["status"] as String

                    if status == "OK" {
                        self.selectedRoute = (dictionary["routes"] as Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>)[0]
                        self.overviewPolyline = self.selectedRoute["overview_polyline"] as Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

                        let legs = self.selectedRoute["legs"] as Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>

                        let startLocationDictionary = legs[0]["start_location"] as Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
                        self.originCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(startLocationDictionary["lat"] as Double, startLocationDictionary["lng"] as Double)

                        let endLocationDictionary = legs[legs.count - 1]["end_location"] as Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
                        self.destinationCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(endLocationDictionary["lat"] as Double, endLocationDictionary["lng"] as Double)

                        self.originAddress = legs[0]["start_address"] as String
                        self.destinationAddress = legs[legs.count - 1]["end_address"] as String

                        self.calculateTotalDistanceAndDuration()                        

                        completionHandler(status: status, success: true)
                    }
                    else {
                        completionHandler(status: status, success: false)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            completionHandler(status: "Destination is nil.", success: false)
        }
    }
    else {
        completionHandler(status: "Origin is nil", success: false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

para regresar la distancia entre 2 puntos no es necesario que uses alguna api de google, puedes hacerlo de manera nativa en ios con CLLocation
lo unico que debes hacer es implementar el siguiente metodo

```
import CoreLocation


let Punto1 = CLLocation(latitude: 5.0, longitude: 5.0)
let Punto2 = CLLocation(latitude: 5.0, longitude: 3.0)

let DistanciaEnMetros = Punto1.distance(from: Punto2)
```

Comment: Esta respuesta no es lo que pide.

Comment: Tienes que dar una respuesta acorde a los requerimientos del OP